# On iOS, how can an app determine if a file is no longer being written to by another process?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, kqueue

My question is very similar to this one: [What is the optimal way to monitor changes in a directory with a kqueue()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972563/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-monitor-changes-in-a-directory-with-a-kqueue) but I'm not satisfied with the answer there.

I have a kqueue setup to be notified when a file is copied to my app's Documents directory. Of course the notification fires as soon as the copying begins, but I want to know when it's completed. Surely there's a better way than polling modification times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the answer seems to be 'no', so I've resorted to polling the modification time of the file(s) in question.

If someone else is able to come up with a better answer, I'd be glad to hear it (and will un-accept this one).

Answer (score 1):

Do you initiate the copying and have control over the filenames ?
Then the easiest solution could be to just copy to a temp file and then after that rename it to it's final name.that way you would know: if this file is there-it ist no longer written to.

Comment: No, these are documents that are copied by the system into my app bundle's Documents directory for file sharing.