# iOS File System Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to monitor the content of the Documents folder for new content. I see that on OSX there is a File Systems Events API. What about iOS? How could I do this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972563/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-monitor-changes-in-a-directory-with-a-kqueue

Comment: Indeed. Thanks! Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181821/notification-of-changes-to-the-iphones-documents-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the optimal way to monitor changes in a directory with a kqueue()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972563/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-monitor-changes-in-a-directory-with-a-kqueue)

Answer (score 0):

[Just implemented this](https://github.com/kennethlaskoski/FileSystemEventPublisher)

README:

FileSystemEventPublisher

A publisher that tracks changes in the file system.

Example usage:

```
let cancellable = DispatchSource.publish(
  .all,
  for: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
)
.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
.sink { event in
  print(event)
}
//.
//.
//.
cancellable.cancel()
```